# Grouping data from nested arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, enums

Assuming the following data tuple containing a person's name, age and the books he has read:

```
list =     [
  ["Peter", 21, ["Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3", "Book 4"],
  ["Amy", 19, ["Book 3", "Book 4"],
  ["Sanders", 32, ["Book 1", "Book 2",],
  ["Charlie", 21, ["Book 4", "Book 5", "Book 6"],
  ["Amanda", 21, ["Book 2", "Book 5"]
]
```

What is the optimal way to extract names grouped by the books read, into the following format (basically a an array of arrays containing the book name and an array of names of people who read it)

```
results = [
   ["Book 1", ["Sanders", "Peter"]],
   ["Book 2", ["Sanders" "Amanda", "Peter"]],
   ["Book 3", ["Peter", "Amy"]],
   ["Book 4", ["Charlie", "Peter", "Amy"]],
   ["Book 5", ["Amanda","Charlie"]],
   ["Book 6", ["Charlie"]]
]
```

I've tried the following iterating method which extracts the lists of names and puts them into a hash, with the book title as the keys.

```
book_hash = Hash.new([])
list.each { |name,age,books| 
books { |x|  book_hash[x] = book_hash[x] + [name] }
}
results = book_hash.to_a.sort
```

However, the above method seems rather inefficient when handling large datasets containing millions of names. I've attempted to use the Array.group_by, but so far I'm unable to make it work with nested arrays.

Does anyone have any idea about the above?

Comment: Why are you expecting an array where your solution gives a hash? A hash makes more sense in this case.

Comment: Don't be lazy. You should provide at least enough sample data for your `list` that would correspond to your sample result.

Comment: @sawa My apologies, I've just added some sample data and results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash output. More suitable.

```
list.each_with_object({}) do |(name, age, books), hash|
  books.each do |book|
    (hash[book] ||= []) << name    
  end
end
```

If you must make it an array, then append a `.to_a` to the output of the above.

Comment: This did the trick, but since I'm running 1.8.7 I opted for for .each instead of .each_with_object. Thanks!